# model.fit and model.predict errors

Tags: python

Having 2 issues. First, when I have test images not 150 x 150, it crashes, even though I have the line: img.resize((150,150)) before the line that causes the crash, "result = model.predict(img)"

Error message is- ValueError: Input 0 of layer "sequential" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 150, 150, 3), found shape=(None, 499, 381, 3)

Second crash occurs during the execution of this line, "model.fit". It sometimes crashes part way through the epochs. It displayed too many lines of error messages to post here, so here are the first and last messages. I can post more of them if needed -

tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1816] UNKNOWN: UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x00000203FDBB87C0>

last line error message - PIL.UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x00000203FDBB87C0>
[[{{node PyFunc}}]]
[[IteratorGetNext]] [Op:__inference_train_function_1608]

Any idea why? I have plenty of RAM and SSD.

Thanks.

```
from keras.models import load_model, Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D,Flatten,Activation,Dense,MaxPooling2D,Dropout
from tensorflow.keras import optimizers
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator, img_to_array
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import os
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
 
trainRescale = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
img_width = 150
img_height = 150
 
traindata = trainRescale.flow_from_directory('dog-vs-cat-classification/train', target_size = (150,150), batch_size = 32,  class_mode = 'binary')
 
model=Sequential()
 
model.add(Conv2D(32,(3,3),activation='relu',input_shape=(img_width,img_height,3)))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(Conv2D(64,(3,3),activation='relu'))         
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))                                                                                                         
model.add(Conv2D(64,(3,3),activation='relu')) 
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2))) 
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(64,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(1,activation='sigmoid'))
 
model.compile(loss = 'binary_crossentropy', optimizer = 'adam', metrics = ['accuracy'])
 
model.fit(traindata, steps_per_epoch = 8, epochs = 20) 
 
model.save_weights('model_weights.h5')
model.save('model_keras.h5')
 
testImage = os.listdir('dog-vs-cat-classification/test/')
 
for image in testImage:
    img = Image.open('dog-vs-cat-classification/test/' + image)
    img.resize((150,150))
    print("test image", testImage)
    img = img_to_array(img)
    img = np.expand_dims(img, axis=0)
 
    print("pre-predict img", img)
    result = model.predict(img)
 
    if result[0][0] >=0.5:
        prediction = 'dog'
    else:
        prediction = 'cat'    
 
print("image", image, "is a: ", prediction)
```

Answer (score 1):

one of your problem might be fix by changing

```
img = img.resize((150,150))
```

because resize isn't inplace function

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: you should just change img.resize((150,150)) to img = img.resize((150,150))